# WSO2 Bps 3.6 org.activiti.engine.ActivitiOptimisticLockingException

Tags: wso2, wso2-business-process

We've faced with following exception. After some digging around it we've found that our service task has been executed several time with very small interval - like 50ms. How it could be possible that service task was executing 3 times as we suppose it to be executed only once?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found that it was problem with our configuration. We had some kind of mediator between our WSO2 server and Kafka client. So we had situation when mediator has send rest call to WSO2 before it committed it's transaction.